adding date in elasticsearch index name doesn't work
I have been using the following code for the elasticsearch output plugin of a logstash, but it creates the index named as mt-raw-00001
        output {
          elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "${ECK_ES_HOSTS}" ]
            user => "${ECK_ES_USER}"
            password => "${ECK_ES_PASSWORD}"
            ssl_certificate_authorities => "${ECK_ES_SSL_CERTIFICATE_AUTHORITY}"
            index => "mt-raw-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            # index => "mt-raw"
            data_stream => false
            ilm_enabled => "true"
            ilm_pattern => "00001"
            ilm_rollover_alias => "mt-raw"
            ilm_policy => "mt-ilm"
            manage_template => "true"
            template_name => "mt"
          }

I tried with
index => "mt-raw-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
and
index => "mt-raw-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
but the result is the same.
How can I resolve this issue?

Setting ilm_enabled => true tells logstash to manage the index name itself, so it ignores the index option (and warns you it is doing so). If you want to manage the index name yourself then do not enable ILM.
